# How to query songs list in android (excluding a specific folder) using cursorloader?

Tags: android

Following is my code to fetch all the songs from android device:

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
        musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);

music_column_index=musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
```

The above gives me list of all the songs in any of the folders in the device however i dont want to fetch songs from a specific folder(say music_folder).Can somebody help to modify the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +" NOT LIKE '%/music_folder/%'";
        musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, selection, null, null);

music_column_index=musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
```

Comment: Thnx a lot E PLayer this was a old post nevertheless thnx for your answer!

Comment: E Player can you please tell me what if i want to pass one more selection say for songs.i.e where song size less than 1 Mb?

Comment: String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +" NOT LIKE '%/music_folder/%' AND "+ MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE +"<"+1048576;//1MB = 1048576 Bytes;